# Bind to a collection's view and just call ToString() in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, gridview, collections

I'm binding a GridView to a collection of objects that look like this:

```
public class Transaction
{
   public string PersonName { get; set; }
   public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
   public MoneyCollection TransactedMoney { get; set;}
}
```

`MoneyCollection` simply inherits from `ObservableCollection<T>`, and is a collection of `MyMoney` type object.

In my GridView, I just want to bind a column to the `MoneyCollection`'s `ToString()` method.  However, binding it directly to the `TransactedMoney` property makes every entry display the text "(Collection)", and the `ToString()` method is never called.

Note that *I do not want to bind to the items in MoneyCollection*, I want to bind directly to the property itself and just call `ToString()` on it.

I understand that it is binding to the collection's default view. So my question is - how can I make it bind to the collection in such a way that it calls the `ToString()` method on it?

This is my first WPF project, so I know this might be a bit noobish, but pointers would be very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a `IValueConverter` implementation that calls ToString() on the bound collection and returns it and use this converter in the XAML binding expression.

Comment: I'll do this if I have to. It seems like there should be a simpler way?

Answer (score 4):

You can add property StringRepresentation or something like this in `MyMoney` class. If you do not want to affect this class, you should write a wrapper - `MyMoneyViewModel` which will have all needed properties. This is a common way. HIH!

Comment: public string AsString { get { return this.ToString(); } } or something. Then bind to AsString.