# how to prevent using global DataTemplate without specifiying new one

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol, itemtemplate

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyType}">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

I have a default DataTemplate for MyType.
want to prevent using it below without having to specify a real DataTemplate

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{whateverList of MyType}" ItemTemplate="{x:Null}"/>
```

`ItemTemplate="{x:Null}"` doesn't get the job done -> shows default DataTemplate
would be happy with "ToString()" display

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the default data  template for the type, you will have to specify a different one:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{listOfMyType}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <!-- Whatever -->
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

There is some more discussion about this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076893/84873), including another's attempt at using `{x:Null}` for the template.

If your template needs to bind to the `ToString()` for your type (and no property exists in the type to do this for you), you'll need to use an `IValueConverter`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925799/84873).